# how big should the /boot directory be in a CentOS 7 server?

Tags: centos, mount, boot

I am installing CentOS 7 in a 200GB partition of a 2TB hard drive whose other partitions will later become managed by this master CentOS 7 installation.  **How big should the boot mount installation be?**

In my CentOS 7 devbox, navigating to the `/boot` directory and typing `du` results in about 195MB.  So is 230MB big enough for the boot mount point capacity?  What factors should I consider in planning the size of the `/boot` mount point capacity?

Comment: Factors include a) how many kernel updates you'll install and b) how lazy you are about cleaning up old ones.

Comment: @thrig can you please comment on the comment I left on the other user's answer below? I figure you might be on the site more frequently than he,  given his low rep. Thank you.

Comment: 500 MB to 1 GB for /boot.Size of linux kernel grew up.You can boot up with few kernel version

Answer (score 1):

Using the linked resources it seems that a large kernel (a default kernel from Ubuntu for example that has support for more devices that you probably need but provide the most compatibility) can be about 1.8MB in size including kernel and modules.

Although if you removed features you could shrink the kernel down and save space.

So with 200MB (the Fedora 22 recommended /boot size) you could have quite a few kernels in the partition.

So the answer is how many kernels you think you might want to store and how often you want to delete old ones.

https://superuser.com/questions/370586/how-can-a-linux-kernel-be-so-small
https://serverfault.com/questions/334663/what-is-the-recommended-size-for-a-linux-boot-partition

Comment: But doesnt the du result in my OP above indicate that the 200 MB is already almost full?

Comment: It appears RHEL7-class systems include a ~40MB rescue image, so that's 20% of a 200M partition right there. A centos7 test virt I did an `autopart` on ended up with a 500M `/boot`, so using whatever KickStart gives you might be a good starting point (I'd assume the RHEL docs will recommend the same as what KickStart does).